# Do natural melee weapons (from racial traits) trigger Improved Divine Smite?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin, racial-traits, natural-weapon

Following up on 
[Does Improved Divine Smite trigger when a paladin makes an unarmed strike?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142250/42805)

> Improved Divine Smite will not trigger on an unarmed strike.

### Context

The paladin in my campaign – covered in [my previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142250/42805) – is a minotaur. This means he could attack with his horns, to potentially trigger Improved Divine Smite.

**Minotaur**, [Unearthed Arcana: Centaurs and Minotaurs](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Centaur.pdf):

> *Horns.* Your horns are natural melee weapons, with which you’re proficient. When you hit with
>   them, the target takes piercing damage equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier.

**Paladin**, PHB page 85:

> *Improved Divine Smite.* By 11th level, whenever you hit a creature with a melee weapon, the creature takes an extra 1d8 radiant damage.

### Question

**Do natural melee weapons from racial traits trigger Improved Divine Smite?**

In other words, do natural weapons count as melee weapons? Or is there some other rule that categorizes/treats *natural melee weapons* differently from other melee weapons?

For my campaign I'm mostly interested in the natural melee weapon from minotaurs. I'm assuming, however, the same rules would apply for other natural melee weapons gained through racial traits – e.g. a lizardfolk's Bite, tabaxi's Claw, centaur's Hoove, etc. If this assumption is wrong, please enlighten me.

Comment: Just so you know, the minotaur race from that UA has been published in a slightly modified(?) form in the Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes, if the racial rule calls them weapons

*(This answer has been updated to reflect the apparent shift in the wording of the rules since Explorer's Guide to Wildemount. The original answer is below the horizontal rule.)*

User Mavoc points out that the wording for most of the races with natural weapons has been revised. The online version of those races (and printed versions since Explorer's Guide to Wildemount) uses slightly different wording from previous publishings:

> Your talons are natural weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes.

Further, it seems this wording change "which you can use to make unarmed strikes" has ben retroactively applied to virtually all races that have natural weapons on D&D Beyond.

For context, the PHB (page 119) states:

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons).

So, while general rule that unarmed strikes can't work with Improved Divine Smite because unarmed strikes aren't weapons, the rule for races like the Aarakocra, specifically says that the relevant anatomy *is* a [natural weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/146855/48793). This would allow it to work with abilities that require a weapon despite the fact that an unarmed strike is being made.

---

As your other linked answer states, Unarmed Strikes do not work for Improved Divine Strike because [the rules say Unarmed Strikes are not weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks):

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an **unarmed strike**: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons).

But the [racial ability for Minotaur horns](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Centaur.pdf) *specifically* says the horns *are* a weapon:

> Your horns are natural melee weapons

What is happening here is that there is a specific rule/allowance for the Minotaur that is similar to (but different from) a general prohibition.

The minotaur is *not* making an Unarmed Strike (a head-butt). It is making an attack with a weapon which happens to be located on its head.

Contrast this with [the Aarakocra's Talons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra#AarakocraTraits):

> **Talons**
>
> You are proficient with your unarmed strikes, which deal 1d4 slashing damage on a hit.

[(Hat tip to Justin for the Aarakocra example)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/142691/48793)

Also, [Jeremy Crawford has tweeted an affirmation of this answer](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/996536482306273280).

Comment: There is a sageadvice to this same question: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/06/06/does-the-natural-melee-weapon-of-the-minotaurs-horns-works-with-divine-smite/

Comment: What would you say about the Tabaxi whose natural weapon is not described as a "melee weapon"? "In addition, your claws are natural weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes."

Comment: @med It's frustrating when the rules are written sloppy. I think that's a case where it's simplest to assume that the Tabaxi claws are melee weapons, even though they're not designated as melee. They certainly aren't ranged weapons. A thought occurs to me. If they "*can* be used to make unarmed strikes" might that be interpreted to mean that they are weapons that can be counted as making unarmed strikes with (not just weapon attacks)? Lots of room for DM interpretation there, it seems.

Comment: @Rykara Yeah the fact that Minotaur, Aarakocra, and Tabaxi have their modified unarmed strikes written different is... annoying to say the least

Comment: Aarakocra Talons have since received errata and AFAIK, all racial unarmed strike features also count as Natural Weapons now.

Comment: The most recent printing of Aarakocra in the Wildemount book, also all digital sources updated to the newer version.

* Talons. Your talons are natural weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes. If you hit with them, you deal slashing damage equal to 1d4 + your Strength modifier, instead of the bludgeoning damage normal for an unarmed strike.

Comment: The only races that have an unarmed attack that don't count as a Natural weapon that I could find are the Satyr and the Longtooth Shifter.

Comment: I don't think they will ever bother making errata for EEPC, as they didn't bother when Xanathar's reworked some of the spells.

Comment: Might be worth putting the most up-to-date info at the top.

Comment: @Tho Yeah, I think you're right. Good call, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## Yes, if it says they are weapons

The Minotaur race *Horns* racial feature says (emphasis mine):

> Your horns are natural **melee weapons**, with which you’re
>   proficient. When you hit with them, the target takes piercing damage
>   equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier.

Divine smite says:

> By 11th level, whenever you hit a creature with a **melee weapon**, the creature takes
>   an extra 1d8 radiant damage.

So, in this case it is valid, as it says that your horns are weapons. However, this only applies to the Minotaur race. Racial attack abilities vary between races. For instance, the *Aarakockra* race's *Talon* racial feature says:

> You are proficient with your unarmed strikes, which deal 1d4 slashing damage on a hit.

In this case, it does not say that the talons are weapons, and it therefore follows the ['it does not work' unarmed strikes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142250/does-improved-divine-smite-trigger-when-a-paladin-makes-an-unarmed-strike?noredirect=1&lq=1) path.

You can tell the difference between the racial attacks eligible for Improved Divine Smite, and those ineligible, as the valid ones say that it is a weapon, and the not valid ones don't.

Comment: There is a sageadvice to this same question: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/06/06/does-the-natural-melee-weapon-of-the-minotaurs-horns-works-with-divine-smite/

Comment: What would you say about the Tabaxi whose natural weapon is not described as a "melee weapon"? "In addition, your claws are natural weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes."

Comment: The Aarakockra Talons have been updated in their most recent printing and are now natural weapons.

Comment: @Mavoc ..and now with MotM, all racial attacks have had the "natural weapons" wording removed.