# Can you use an unarmed strike with the Hunter Ranger's Horde Breaker feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, unarmed-combat

The [Hunter Ranger's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Hunter) Horde Breaker feature states:

> Once on each of your turns when you **make a weapon attack**, you can make another attack with the same weapon against a different creature that is within 5 feet of the original target and within **range of your weapon.**

We also know that [unarmed strikes count as weapon attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58158) and in particular the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/sage-advice-compendium) states:

> For example, an unarmed strike counts as a melee weapon attack, even though the attacker’s body isn’t considered a weapon.

However, the Horde Breaker feature states that you must make another attack *within range of your weapon* and unarmed strikes are not weapons. So can you use an unarmed strike with Horde Breaker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No you cannot; Horde Breaker later relies on a weapon

The case here is similar to two others where it *looks* like you could use unarmed strikes but you actually can't:

1. The Savage Attacker feat states:

   > Once per turn when you roll damage for a **melee weapon attack**, you can reroll **the weapon's damage dice** and use either total.

   And then the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/sage-advice-compendium) states:

   > Q. **Does the Savage Attacker feat work with unarmed strikes?**
   >
   > No. Savage Attacker relies on a weapon’s damage dice, and an unarmed strike isn’t a weapon (a point that was clarified in the Player’s Handbook errata).
2. The Divine Smite feature states:

   > [...] When you hit a creature with a **melee weapon attack**, you can expend one spell slot to deal radiant damage to the target, in addition to **the weapon's damage.**

   And then [this well upvoted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/142256/36521) to the question "[Does Improved Divine Smite trigger when a paladin makes an unarmed strike?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142250)" states:

   > [...] Note that normal Divine Smite also does not work with unarmed strikes [...]
   >
   > Even though an unarmed strike is technically a melee weapon attack, the rule for Divine Smite also says that the damage is done by a weapon and an unarmed strike is not considered a weapon [...]

The scenario here is the same as those; though Horde Breaker *looks* like it would work with unarmed strikes it actually still requires a weapon, and unarmed strikes are not weapons:

> Once on each of your turns when you **make a weapon attack**, you can make another attack **with the same weapon** against a different creature that is within 5 feet of the original target and within range of your weapon.

Comment: Would this not work with a race's ability that specifically calls it a Natural Weapon, such as the Lizardfolk's Bite, the Tortle's or Tabaxi's Claws, or the Minotaur's Horns? Considering that these special abilities specifically call it a Natural Weapon that you can make Unarmed Strikes with, I'd be curious if that would work or not.

Comment: @JayKay I *think* this answers that but I'll keep looking: "[Do natural melee weapons (from racial traits) trigger Improved Divine Smite?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142688)". Also "[What are natural weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146855)".