# How much damage does an unarmed bugbear deal?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage, unarmed-combat, bugbear

The 5th edition *Monster Manual* gives Bugbear stats for morning star and javelin attacks, but not for unarmed attacks.

I improvised 1d4 +2, but how much damage can an unarmed bugbear actually deal?

Comment: Also related: [How much damage does a punch deal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108703/33707)

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [How much damage does a weaponless skeleton do?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113366/how-much-damage-does-a-weaponless-skeleton-do)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The unarmed strike will deal 3 damage

The [bugbear's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bugbear) statblock lists it as having 15 Strength, a +2 modifier, and we know from the section on "[Melee Attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks)" that:

> On a hit, an unarmed strike deals bludgeoning damage equal to 1 + your Strength modifier. You are proficient with your unarmed strikes.

Now we need to know the Bugbear's proficiency bonus and we can look to page 8 of the *Monster Manual* which provides a lot of math behind the Monster therein. A chart shows that a CR of 1 provides a proficiency bonus of +2 which is consistent with all of its attacks and skill proficiencies (though note it does have expertise in stealth), and so we can conclude the following:

The Bugbear has a +4 to hit with an unarmed strike (+2 Strength modifier, +2 proficiency bonus) and it will deal 1 + 2 bludgeoning damage (the basic formula for an unarmed strike with a Strength modifier of +2).

---

Of note the Bugbear's Brute ability will not work with unarmed strikes as it states:

> **A melee weapon** deals one extra die of its damage when the bugbear hits with it (included in the attack).

Unarmed strikes are *not* considered weapons and so this feature will not benefit them however the Surprise Attack feature will still work as normal:

> If the bugbear surprises a creature and hits it with **an attack** during the first round of combat, the target takes an extra 7 (2d6) damage from **the attack**.

No part of this requires a weapon, only an attack and an unarmed strike is an attack.